# Is there a plugin in Eclipse for applying tags to files?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have searched for such a plugin but haven't found any. I need a facility to "tag" my java files. Similar to tagging on stackoverflow.

I want to be able to group my files based on projects/tasks I wam working on. Mylyn helps a little but it dynamically changes the context (list of resources associated with a task) based on various factors.

I just want a basic tagging facility for all the files in my workspace.

Answer (score 3):

http://taggerplugin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Resource Tagger](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-818.html) which may do what you are looking for. Report back on what you find works please.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tagging them with tag interfaces -- these will persist across checkins and different workspaces.

Something like

```
public interface Observer {}  // no required methods
```

and then when you want to tag a class as an observer, you do

```
public class SomeClass implements Observer {...}
```

In eclipse, you can then open a hierarchy view on the tag interface (Observer in this instance) and see everything that implements it.

You could also use annotations for tagging as well.

In both cases, you could also write code that reflects your code base to find tagged classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Mylyn, try right-clicking on the file you want to "tag" and select "mark as landmark". The landmarked file will then stay put in your context.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late , but you can try to use eclipse workingset to group source files.
Create as many working set as you need and add files to each of them; after that you juste have to use explorer select or deselect workingSet option to switch between group of files

HTH !